# Loading .owl files in marklogic

Tags: owl, marklogic, mlcp

Is it possible to load .owl files using mlcp?
I tried with `-input_file_type rdf` but it gives error as below:

> bin/mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 9010 -username uname
>   -password pwd -mode local -input_file_path /home/user/semantics/data -input_file_type  rdf -input_file_pattern '.*.owl'
>
> FATAL contentpump.RDFReader: dbpedia1.owl: Element or attribute do not
>   match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. FATAL
>   contentpump.RDFReader: dbpedia2.owl: Element or attribute do not match
>   QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of that owl file?

Comment: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/diseasome/resource/diseases/2582>       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>         <http://purl.org/net/tcm/tcm.lifescience.ntu.edu.tw/id/disease/Hepatoblastoma> .
<http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/diseasome/resource/diseases/2385>       <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs>         <http://purl.org/net/tcm/tcm.lifescience.ntu.edu.tw/id/disease/Favism> .

Comment: It looks like perhaps it's expecting the RDF/XML serialization of the RDF mapping of an OWL ontology when it sees a .owl file.  What happens if you just change the file extension to `.ttl` or `.n3`?

Answer (score 3):

MarkLogic documentation lists [the supported triples file formats](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/loading#id_81259):

- .rdf
- .ttl
- .json
- .n3
- .nt
- .nq
- .trig

Maybe you convert your .owl file to one of those formats, at which point you could use MLCP to load it. I tried plugging your example into [a format converter](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/), but that didn't work. Perhaps it's because we only have a snippet here.

Comment: It looks like the snippet it Turtle/N3, but pasting it into a comment without code ticks means that the URIs are rendered as links without the `http://`, so they won't be legal URIs.  The converter might well complain about that (or just about malformed Turtle/N3, since it's a snippet out of context).

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic should be able to process .owl files, but I think Joshua is right that MarkLogic is expecting .owl files to contain RDF/XML. You can also see that from the list of Mimetypes in the Admin interface. It lists the .owl extension as 'application/owl+xml', and RDF/XML seems to be the more common serialization of OWL.

Might just be that if you rename the file to .nt that it works..

HTH!